# Why redux's middleware uses three levels of return

Tags: redux, middleware

I just have a question about redux's applyMiddleware enhancer and it's usage, why middlewares in applyMiddleware should be mapped first and why the middleware should use three levels of return.

What's wrong with the way it's written below?

```js
const applyMiddleware = (...middlewares) => {
  return (createStore) => (reducer, originState) => {
    const store = createStore(reducer, originState);

    const dispatch = compose(...middlewares)(store);

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch,
    };
  };
};

export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(({
    getState,
    dispatch
  }) => {
    return (action) => {
      if (typeof action === 'function') {
        action(dispatch);
        return;
      }
      dispatch(action);
    };
  })
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware#understanding-middleware

Comment: https://redux.js.org/faq/design-decisions#why-does-the-middleware-signature-use-currying I have found this